# recursively downloading all the folders and subfolder from webpage

Tags: wget, web-crawler

I would like to download a directory from webpage. i am trying to do using wget and crawl but i am not able to download the whole directory as it was there in web-page or in any-other way.
suppose the web-page is abcd.com/ddd/bbb/A. inside A there is information relevant that start with A. my target is to download what ever the file is there in A i.e recursively downloading all the subfolder in A if available.

Answer (score 0):

If all the documents are accessible via plain HTML links, then the following should work:

```
wget -np -r -l0 http://abcd.com/ddd/bbb/A/
```

This is assuming that `A` is a directory; if it is not, then you should omit the trailing slash and accept downloading everything in `bbb` instead.

`-np` omits parent directories. `-r` toggles recursive downloads, and `-l0` selects infinite download depth. The latter is of course risky in case there are infinite symlink loops or similar constructs. So it might be safer to plug in a reasonable estimate of the maximal link chain needed to reach all desired documents. I often use `-l5` myself.